# IIS 7 Authentication - Allow only Smart-Card logon certificates

Tags: c#, iis, ssl, certificate, smartcard

I work in an organization which its users who allowed to open the application must be logged in using a Smart-card.

Whenever a user join (almost daily) we develop new smart-cards for that user.

My problem is that with some config changes, the users can log-in without using a Smart-card, just using their own windows certificates.

What is the best way authentication way to reach that goal?

Is there a build-in way in IIS 7 to allow the access ONLY to  certificates which contain Smart-card logon?

the application was developed in C#.

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can read from the enhanced key usage from the certificate and check whether the certificate you are authenticating is smart card or not.
Typically, your enhanced key usage for a non-smart card would be client authentication, and your enhanced key usage for a smart card would be client authentication + smart card logon; here's a sample code I've writen last week to achieve similar things as your requirement:

```
var validCertsAssignedToUserOrderBySmartCardValidFromDate = from cert in validCertsAssignedToUser
                                                                        from ext in cert.Extensions.OfType<X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension>()
                                                                        from usage in ext.EnhancedKeyUsages.OfType<Oid>()
                                                                        let isSmartCard = (ext.Oid.FriendlyName == "Enhanced Key Usage" && usage.FriendlyName == "Smart Card Logon") ? 0 : 1
                                                                        orderby isSmartCard
                                                                            , cert.NotBefore descending
                                                                        select cert;
```

in terms of IIS 7 build-in way, I am not aware of any, but I don't think it difficult to implement programmatically